# Decision to use KEY or UNIQUE KEY

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-index

I understand that UNIQUE KEY is a unique index and KEY is a non-unique index. I have read that in case of unique index'es inserting data might result in some IO.

If we don't have to rely on the DB for unique-ness and we still want fast lookup's using column 'b' would you suggest to use a non unique index (KEY) instead of a unique index (UNIQUE KEY)?

Comment: If using unique indexes would be bad, then why do we have those? It is clear and clean DB design to use them if the data is unique.

Comment: Under what circumstances can you not rely on db for uniqueness? Any insert operation results in some I/O, it's not like it's avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both unique and non-unique indexes result in I/O operations for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` statements.  The amount of index overhead should be pretty much the same.  The difference is that unique indexes might result in a failure of an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` under normal use (of course, the operations might fail for other reasons, such as disk being full, but that is an unusual circumstance).

I don't understand this statement: "If we don't have to rely on the DB for unique-ness".  A `UNIQUE` attribute in a table is a description of the column/columns that comprise the key.  One of the functions of a database is to maintain the integrity of the data, so let the database do what it is designed for.

As for performance, I don't think there is a significant difference between unique and non-unique indexes.  Unique indexes may be *slightly* more optimized for certain operations because the compiler knows that a single lookup returns only one row.  The difference between an index lookup and an index scan that returns one row is probably pretty small in practice.